# Features of applying CSS styles in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I can write CSS styles this way:

```
.myClass {
  backdgoun-color: red;
}

.myClass.yellow {
  backdgoun-color: yellow;
}
```

And then I can use it in my React component this way:

```
<div className="myClass yellow"/>
```

And it works very well. But how I can repeate it if I use module.css in my appliction?

Comment: What do you mean by "repeate it if I use module.css in my appliction" ? Do you mean CSS modules that you import within the JavaScript?

Comment: I mean what should the className entry look like in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS modules you can do things as follows:

```css
.button {
  color: blue;
}

.button.warning {
  color: red;
}
```

```
import styles from './Button.module.css';

const Button = ({ isWarning }) => {
  const classNames = [styles.button];
  if (isWarning) {
    classNames.push(styles.warning);
  }

  return <button className={classNames.join(' ')}>
}
```